# Memory-mapping 2D array using boost

Tags: c++, boost, memory-mapping

I am trying to use boost to map a file onto memory having 3 floats per row (x,y,z coordinates of points). I am trying to store the data in cl_float3 type (for openCL) but it seems not to work. This is my code:

```
cl_float3 *data;
boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source file;
size = 785444;    // size of the file
int numBytes = size*sizeof(cl_float)*3;
file.open(filename,numBytes);
if(file.is_open()) {
    data = (cl_float3*)file.data();
    file.close();
}
```

Its giving access violation error for reading violation when I try to use data array. Any help?

Comment: Is it really "3 floats per row", or is it "3 ASCII-encoded character strings representing an approximate floating point value per row" - i.e. is it the binary 4-byte representation of a float, or a human-readable text representation like "3.141593"?

Comment: Yeah I tried the raw binary file as input and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing the file as soon as you open it.  I haven't read the documentation for boost's memory mapped files, but you probably need to leave the file open.

```
if (file.is_open()) {
    data = (cl_float3*) file.data();
    file.close(); // remove this line
}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. But its still giving garbage values for reading in data.

Comment: What format is the file in? This expects raw binary floating point values.

Comment: I tried several formats - ascii(.xyz)/fast binary(.fbi)/binary(.bin). While I dont know whether the formats are raw binaries or not, I am getting either zeros or garbage values always.

Comment: Okay I just converted to raw binary and it seems to work just fine. Thank you!